# What is the proper way to test types?

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, testing, ecmascript-6, jestjs

I am using Jest for unit-testing and I want to test if the variable is an Object. Is there a better way to do it?

```
it('should throw an Error if options is not an Object', () => {
  const error = 'Options should be an Object.'

  expect(() => new Foo([])).toThrow(error)
  expect(() => new Foo(123)).toThrow(error)
  expect(() => new Foo('')).toThrow(error)
  expect(() => new Foo(true)).toThrow(error)
  expect(() => new Foo(NaN)).toThrow(error)
  expect(() => new Foo(null)).toThrow(error)
  expect(() => new Foo(() => {})).toThrow(error)
})
```

Comment: You aren't testing if a variable is an object, you are testing if a constructor can receive anything other than an object. I don't know of any shorter way of doing this, though I would add a test and expect it not to throw when an object *is* passed

Comment: You can do it with Jasmine.  `expect(foo).to.be.a('object')`  or `assert.typeOf(foo, 'object')`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As always a loop might help:

```
 for(const type of [[], 123, '', true, NaN, null])
   expect(() => new Foo(type)).toThrow(error);
```